# Onde criar uma camada Helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ddd

Preciso criar uma camada `Helpers` que conterá classes que serão disponibilizadas para todo o projeto. Essas classes conterão funções como cálculos, limpadores de *string*, enfim, aquelas funções que usamos o tempo todo...

Meu projeto possui as camadas `Presentation`, `Application`, `Domain`, `infra/Data`, `infra/crosscutting`.

Pensei em criar a camada `Helpers` dentro de `infra/crosscutting`, é o local certo?

Comment: Na maioria dos projetos que já trabalhei esses tipos de classe sempre estavam na camada de  Crosscutting/Infraestrutura. E se realmente são usadas por todas as camadas então não há lugar melhor que esse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certo ou errado nessas coisas é relativo. Tudo funciona e de forma geral não está caindo aos pedaços. Muitas vezes é preciosismo tentar fazer tão certo assim, desde que **saiba o que está fazendo**. Sem saber até o certo não é bom.

Acho seu projeto com camadas demais, mas é só minha opinião generalizada.

Em geral é confuso ter *helpers* genéricos assim, mas tem casos que é a melhor solução. Não temos como responder isto.

Pode ser em *helpers* se organizar bem, não virar um amontoado de coisas. Esses *helpers* podem ser métodos de extensão. Ou podem estar em algum tipo que não seja só um *helper*, talvez até em um tipo já existente. Não pode nem separar demais, nem juntar demais.

Fora isso deve colocar o *helper*, se for adequado ter um, no local onde ele faça mais sentido, pode ser totalmente separado do resto (pelo que passou, parece ser o caso de quase tudo) ou pode ser em uma dessas camadas, depende se é para uso só nela. Não coloque algo em um local específico e use em todo lugar da solução. Separe o que é biblioteca geral da aplicação. Não necessariamente como *helper*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Levando em conta que seu projeto já tem essas camadas e você queria implementar alguns helpers, um jeito de manter tudo organizado e respeitando as camadas seria deixar que o tipo do helper determine em qual camada ele ficará. Se for um helper que tenha a ver com o banco de dados ele ficará na camada de infra, se for um para formatar algo na UI ficará na camada de apresentação e por aí vai.

Isso não é uma lei, é apenas uma maneira de se organizar seus helpers. Tem que usar a organização que mais lhe agradar de acordo com o projeto.